# Is Metallic Mimic the chosen creature type when it enters the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Thalia's Lieutenant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThalia%27s%5d%2b%5bLieutenant%5d) in play and resolve a [Metallic Mimic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMetallic%20Mimic%5d) choosing "Human" does Thalia's Lieutenant get a +1/+1 counter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**

[Metallic Mimic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=423831)

> As Metallic Mimic enters the battlefield, choose a creature type.
>
> Metallic Mimic is the chosen type in addition to its other types.

When you are asked to do something "As X enters the battlefield", you are doing it immediately before it enters. This does not use the stack; when Metallic Mimic resolves you **choose a type and it enters as that type, triggering any appropriate ETBs**, and no one can do anything in between you choosing the type and Mimic hitting the battlefield.

If it instead read:

> When Metallic Mimic enters the battlefield, choose a creature type.

Then it would be a triggered ability; Metallic Mimic would enter the battlefield as a "Shapeshifter", this ability would be put on the stack, and when it resolved you'd get to choose a type (like "Human") and it would become that type. [Thalia's Lieutenant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=409783)'s ability would not be triggered.

Comment: Interesting, never really appreciated the difference between "When X enters the battlefield..." and "As X enters the battlefield...". Nice addition to the answer.

Comment: @Matt Thanks! Whenever an MTG question asks "does X happen", and X doesn't happen, I try to include counterexample Y, where it WILL happen, because I find those super helpful.